# Where is the documentation on resource alias syntax and limitations?

Tags: android, resources, alias

I have an app that uses the same layout for all screen sizes (portrait only). The only difference is a handful of dimensions -- text sizes, margins, padding, etc. -- that vary slightly from one screen size bucket to another. Accordingly, I use a single layout xml file stored in the default layout folder, and have separate dimen.xml files stored in size-specific folders named with the minimum-size qualifiers (values-sw600dp, etc.)

But the Android documentation on Supporting Multiple Screens says that the minimum screen-width qualifiers don't work below Android 3.2. So I need to put dimen.xml files in values-small, values-large, values-xlarge, etc.

In order to avoid having to change the dimen.xml file for the same size (e.g., large and sw600dp), in two places, I'd like to alias one of the references. The very limited documentation I've found on using resource aliases doesn't make it clear whether I can alias a dimen.xml file, or what the correct syntax would be.

My preference is to store the actual dimen.xml file for a given size in the minimum-width folder (e.g., in values-sw600dp) and put an alias in the dimen.xml file in old-style size folder (e.g., in values-large). I think this would be the syntax:

```
   <resources>
     <item type="values" name="dimen">@values-sw600dp/dimen</item>
   </resources>
```

Or would it be this:

```
<resources>
 <item type="values-sw600dp" name="dimen">@values/dimen</item> 
</resources>
```

I can't find any documentation on the syntax for an alias like this, or how the type field is interpreted. Is there any specific documentation like that?

And, is it even possible to do what I want? Can I alias a dimen resource? Is there a limitation such that I would have to store the master dimen.xml file in the default values folder (for example, "dimen_large.xml") and use aliases to refer to it in dimen.xml files in each of the two size folders?